# Pass decorator argument to inner function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am continuing learning python. However I have some idea but faced with implementation problem.
I am using selenium and of cause for each element I have multiple cases like:

```
submit_btn = (By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
revert_btn = (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='revert']")
```

This annoys me much as I am duplicating always By.CSS_SELECTOR or by xpath.
I want to make a decorator that takes path argument and by_what argument that is set by default to "css"
And use to manipulate WebDriver like:

```
@by("[data-qa='selected']")
def save_form(self):
   self.find_element().click()
```

My method find_element looks like:

```
 def find_element(self, locator, time=10):
        try:
            el = WebDriverWait(self.browser, time).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(locator),
                                                         message=f"Can't find elements by locator {locator}")
            return el
        except TimeoutException:
            return False
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return WebDriverWait(self.browser, time).until(ec.staleness_of(locator),
                                                           message=f"Can't find element by locator {locator}")
```

Or maybe another way.
I was trying to create decorator like:

```
def by(selector, what="css", data_qa=True):
    def inner_function(function):
        def wrapper(param):
            if what == "css":
                find_by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            elif what == "xpath":
                find_by = By.XPATH
            if data_qa:
                path = (find_by, f"[data-qa='{param}']")
            else:
                path = (find_by, selector)
            return function(path)

        return wrapper

    return inner_function
```

And would be nice to use it as

```
@by('selected')
def get_selected_el(self)
   # set path returned by decorator to find element method
   self.find_element(smth_returned_by_decorator)
```

So I would like to pass locator as decorator implementation.
How can it be done?

Comment: Seems like what you are hoping is that your decorator will invisibly provide a constant additional parameter to the decorated function - not obvious to me how that’s possible. Maybe just provide that parameter in the function definition like `def get_selected_el(self,by=‘selected’):` which is actually less typing and clearer and can be overridden at call time.

Comment: Yes, thanks, maybe I would like to to smth like in java but seems it looks like crunches. I think it's a good idea to set up keyarg in function

Comment: Assuming the functions are all methods of a class then the decorator could set a class attribute to the parameter of the decorator. But TBH that all seems like more work than specifying the additional parameter with default value in the function definition. Decorators aren’t all-powerful or the solution to everything.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do something like that is to have a parameter in the decorated function that is not exposed in the function returned by the decorator:

```py
# Decorator that automatically forwards an argument
def autoparam(param):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(self):
            f(self, param)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class MyClass:
    def method1(self, param):
        print(param)
    @autoparam('method2 value')
    def method2(self, param):
        self.method1(param)

# Test
obj = MyClass()
# Calling method2 does not require an argument
obj.method2()
# method2 value
```

Comment: Seems like a maintenance nightmare because it looks like the method definition needs a parameter, but when called it doesn’t. Very confusing.

Comment: @barny Well, yes, that is the drawback, you would need to design things so it is clear that this is a "special" parameter provided by "the framework", or simply document it properly in the method docstring. Several web frameworks in Python use a similar idea to convert GET or POST data into function parameters (although usually functions decorated that way are not directly called by the user, but by the web framework itself).